# What are some tools you've built or heard of being built using the tooling API?

Tags: tooling-api

Anything counts as long as the tooling API was critical to the functionality of the project. This includes Andrew Fawcett's Apex wrapper around the API.

https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi

Comment: In order to make this question useful, we'll have to put up a community wiki, but I'm not sure what the point of the question is?

Comment: Yeah I got an alert while asking the question that stackexchange prefers questions that can be definitively answered. I'm more looking to discuss... where should I post this?

Comment: I'm not saying that such a question "can't" exist here (for example, we have a Q&A for force.com IDEs), but for an actual *discussion*, consider the [DeveloperForce forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums) or the [Salesforce Community](https://success.salesforce.com/), which are amenable to such discussions.

Comment: I agree this question is off topic here but am somewhat leery to unilaterally close it...

Comment: @AdrianLarson, I know THIS is off topic, but that was a beautiful sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just about **any** tool that is built for Salesforce developers will touch the Tooling API for some or all of its functionality. The Metadata API alone can't perform all the operations that the Tooling API can. More common would be to use a combination of these two APIs and then some (Streaming API, Partner/REST API, Bulk API)

Here is an extract from [Tools for Development](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/salesforce/4095/tools-for-development/14260/ides#t=201704032305321693073) that I know for sure use the Tooling API:

- [Force.com IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/salesforce/4095/tools-for-development/14260/ides#t=201704032305321693073) – plugin for Eclipse
- [MavensMate](http://mavensmate.com/) – plugin for [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) and [Atom](https://atom.io/) and [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)
- [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/products/fuseit-sfdc-explorer/) - This is a standalone tool (Built by myself and distributed via my current employer)
- [Welkin Suite](https://welkinsuite.com/) – This is a standalone tool;

Even the [Developer Console](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developer_Console) uses the Tooling API for a majority of its calls. It is also used with the Salesforce DX command line.

Comment: Thanks! This is a wonderful list that will lead to some nice reading.